# Why can I replace a file on Windows NTFS that I cannot delete

Tags: windows, directory, ntfs

I came across a curious discovery a few days ago with my windows file system, which uses [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS).

I have a folder within my file system my gradle projects use as a cache. Within this folder, are many different folders containing java .jar files used as dependencies for my project. Typically, these jar files are downloaded from the cloud storage system our project uses for storing these jars. There are three different ways I update these jar files.

1. I can do a complete refresh through my gradle project, in which every jar in my cache is updated. This takes alot of time and is only done when absolutely necessary
2. When I want to get the most recent version of a single jar, I will delete the jar file, and refresh my project. The project internally reaches out to the cloud storage system and downloads a new jar.
3. When I do local development and want to test my changes, sometimes I will replace these jars(overwriting the previous jar) with a jar I developed locally for testing.

However, if any of my java applications using these jars are open, I can only replace the jars, I am unable to delete them. If I attempt to delete them, I receive a `The action can't be completed because the file is open in Java(TM) Platform SE binary.` To delete the jar for following step 2, I have to close my entire project before deleting.

I have read [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8d8ac23d-d5b2-4b38-99c8-84283dcfdfed/block-only-filefolder-deleting-allowing-renaming?forum=winserverfiles), [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320081/you-cannot-delete-a-file-or-a-folder-on-an-ntfs-file-system-volume), & [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/the-action-cant-be-completed-because-the-file-is/381e9f29-50a5-4fa3-b9f2-7b3389293063) on why this is the case, however I cannot find a concrete answer on why Microsoft NTFS will allow me to overwrite the jar with another when it is in use, however I cannot delete the jar while it is in use. Why is this the case?

Comment: Is "replace" a true overwrite, or rename old + create a new file under the old name?

Comment: In the end, though, it's because there are separate flags `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` and `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`.  Consider a shared database file.  All processes have to be able to write (and locking is used to make sure they don't write the same part of the file simultaneously), but no reason to allow deletion because you can't delete "just the part of the file I'm not using right now".

Comment: @Ben In my instance, "replace" is a paste jar from clipboard and say "yes, I am sure I want to overwrite"

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper, if delete access is shared, a file can be renamed anywhere on the volume (e.g. to the recycle bin), but it can't necessarily be deleted if it's memory mapped. Even if deleting the file is allowed, it can't be *unlinked* from the directory until all handles are closed, so it's better to rename it first and then delete it (if possible).

Comment: in your case old file moved to recycle-bin.

Comment: FYI, if the file is memory-mapped, the Memory Manager is an additional player when it comes to deleting a file. The file system calls [`MmFlushImageSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-mmflushimagesection) with a `MmFlushForDelete` flush type. However, there's a back door around this in some cases. You can open the file with `DELETE` access and the flag `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`. This uses an `MmFlushForWrite` flush instead.